# Rails singular route issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have an `account/settings` page people can visit to update their account. It's a singular resource, so they can (or should) only be able to update their own account settings. I'm running into a weird URL format when there are form errors displayed.

If they are on `/account/settings/edit` and try to submit the form with errors (not a valid email address, for example) they are redirected to `/account/settings.1` where it shows them what went wrong (in our example, not a valid email address).

Everything "works" but I was wondering why there is a `.1` being appended to the URL. I figured they would be sent back to `account/settings` or `account/settings/edit` where they can correct the error. Am I doing something wrong?

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :account do
  resource :settings, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]
end
```

**settings_controller.rb**

```
def edit
  @account = Account.find(session[:account][:id])
end

def update
  @account = Account.find(session[:account][:id])
  if @account.update_attributes(params[:account])
    redirect_to account_settings_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

**rake routes**

```
edit_account_settings  GET  /account/settings/edit(.:format)  account/settings#edit
     account_settings  GET  /account/settings(.:format)       account/settings#show
     account_settings  PUT  /account/settings(.:format)       account/settings#update
```

Comment: can you please post the html of generated form from your view? Btw there's nothing wrong with this behavior, the only strange thing is .1 at the end of the url. I guess your account id is somehow misinterpreted as a format.

Comment: Can't help you with what you've posted, the error is in your views if it's anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you generate your paths using `edit_account_settings_path`, NOT `edit_account_settings_path(@user)`. For singular resources you shouldn't pass in a resource, because, as you say, there is only one of them.